# How to align the y axis country labels to the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm making a chart in D3.js, but I need an expert help how to align the y axis country labels to the left. Right now they are aligned to the right.

This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 90},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// csv data
d3.csv("XYZ.csv", function(data) {
        
  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([ 0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d){
             return "$" + d;
        }).ticks(10))
        .selectAll("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

        
  // Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, height ])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.country; }))
    .padding(.1);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  //Bars
  svg.selectAll("myRect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", x(0) )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.country); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.price); })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
    .attr("fill", "red")

})

</script>
```

I tried to resolve it by adding to the y axis:
.attr("transform", "translate(-60, 0)")
.attr("text-anchor", "start");

but it moves and aligns to the left not only the country labels, but also the vertical axis line.

The data points from the csv file are as follows: [csv file data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJkVX.png) with two columns "country" and "price"

Would you be able to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to apply text-anchor="start" to only the labels in the y axis? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right Guttersohn.

Comment: what is `data` in    `.domain(data.map(function(d) {` here?

Comment: Can you supply the ``"XYZ.csv"` so we can reproduce this perhaps?

Comment: Hi Mark, I would gladly supply the csv file, but because of some reason it does not allow me to attach it. I only managed to provide a link to a picture of it in the  "csv file data points" hyperlink above. If you know how I can attach the csv, your advice is welcome. Thank you Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN D3, to apply changes to the text in the axis, you need to specifically select it after creating the element and then apply your attributes.

If you inspect your axis using dev tools, you'll see the labels are stored under group tags with the class name "domain". So you can select and then apply text-anchor like so:

```
d3.selectAll('.tick text').attr('text-anchor','start')
```

I'd also suggest adding a class name to the g tag for the axis. This way, if you have more than one chart on a page, you can make your changes more specific.